# Count calls of a method that may or may not be called inside a decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I have this class:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = {}
    def check_cache(method):
        def wrapper(self):
            if method.__name__ in self.cache:
                print('Got it from the cache!')
                return self.cache[method.__name__]
            print('Got it from the api!')
            self.cache[method.__name__] = method(self)
            return self.cache[method.__name__]
        return wrapper
    @check_cache
    def expensive_operation(self):
        return get_data_from_api()

def get_data_from_api():
    "This would call the api."
    return 'lots of data'
```

The idea is that I can use the `@check_cache` decorator to keep the `expensive_operation` method from calling an api additional times if the result is already cached.

This works fine, it seems.

```
>>> sc.expensive_operation()
Got it from the api!
'lots of data'
>>> sc.expensive_operation()
Got it from the cache!
'lots of data'
```

But I would love to be able to test it with another decorator:

```
import unittest

class SomeClassTester(SomeClass):
    def counted(f):
        def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
            wrapped.calls += 1
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        wrapped.calls = 0
        return wrapped
    @counted
    def expensive_operation(self):
        return super().expensive_operation()


class TestSomeClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_api_is_only_called_once(self):
        sc = SomeClassTester()
        sc.expensive_operation()
        self.assertEqual(sc.expensive_operation.calls, 1) # is 1
        sc.expensive_operation()
        self.assertEqual(sc.expensive_operation.calls, 1) # but this goes to 2

unittest.main()
```

The problem is that the `counted` decorator counts the number of times the `wrapper` function is called, not this inner function.

How do I count that from `SomeClassTester`?

Comment: This is working for me (AssertionError: 2 != 1) ? or you want it that way, you want to count, original expensive_operation which you have decorated twice?

Comment: I would like the 2nd assertion to be 1, because the method would not be called a 2nd time but rather would return the value of the cached call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to do this, without modifying the base class to provide hooks or changing the whole decorated function in derived class based on internal knowledge of base class. Though there is a third way based on internal working of cache decorator, basically change your cache dict so that it counts

```
class CounterDict(dict):
  def __init__(self, *args):
    super().__init__(*args)
    self.count = {}

  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    try:
      self.count[key] += 1
    except KeyError:
      self.count[key] = 1
    return super().__setitem__(key, value)


class SomeClassTester(SomeClass):
    def __init__(self):
      self.cache = CounterDict()

class TestSomeClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_api_is_only_called_once(self):
        sc = SomeClassTester()
        sc.expensive_operation()
        self.assertEqual(sc.cache.count['expensive_operation'], 1) # is 1
        sc.expensive_operation()
        self.assertEqual(sc.cache.count['expensive_operation'], 1) # is 1
```

Comment: This is perfect because I never have to modify my base class. Very creative!

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy way to do this. Your current test applies the decorators in the wrong order. You want `check_cache(counted(expensive_operation))`, but you're getting the `counted` decorator on the outside instead: `counted(check_cache(expensive_operation))`.

There's no easy way to fix this within the `counted` decorator, because by the time it gets called, the original function is already wrapped up by the `check_cache` decorator, and there's no easy way to change the wrapper (it holds its reference to the original function in a closure cell, which is read-only from the outside).

One possible way to make it work is to rebuild the whole method with the decorators in the desired order. You can get a reference to the original method from the closure cell:

```
class SomeClassTester(SomeClass):
    def counted(f):
        def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
            wrapped.calls += 1
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        wrapped.calls = 0
        return wrapped
    expensive_operation = SomeClass.check_cache(
        counted(SomeClass.expensive_operation.__closure__[0].cell_value)
    )
```

This is of course far from ideal, since you need to know exactly what decorators are being applied on the method in `SomeClass` in order to apply them again properly. You also need to know the internals of those decorators so that you can get the right closure cell (the `[0]` index may not be correct if the other decorator gets changed to differently).

Another (perhaps better) approach might be to change `SomeClass` in such a way that you can inject your counting code in between the changed method and the expensive bit you want to count. For example, you could have the real expensive part be in `_expensive_method_implementation`, while the decorated `expensive_method` is just a simple wrapper that calls it. The test class can override the `_implementation` method with its own decorated version (which might even skip the actually expensive part and just return dummy data). It doesn't need to override the regular method or mess with its decorators.